# Custom fonts aren't displaying when viewing Flutter website

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

Is anyone else experience this issue?

My custom fonts are working fine when running locally but once I deploy my website to Firebase the custom fonts are no longer showing.

Is this happening because I am pointing to a local font in my `pubspec.yaml` instead of network?

e.g.

this `'C:/../../assets/fonts/font.ttf'` to this `http://website.com/assets/fonts/font.ttf`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hello @Chris please have a look at the image maybe it helps you

Step 1:-

[image]

Step 2:-
always use relative paths

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind, I fixed it.

It's because the file name had spaces in it e.g. `font name.ttf` instead of `font-name.ttf`